# Can ZF be subsumed in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Assuming that $\sf ZF$ is consistent, is it the case that for every consistent recursively enumerable theory $\sf T $ that extends the theory $\sf ZF+\neg C $, in the language of set theory, there is a model $(M, \in)$ of $\sf ZFC$ and a set $ M^- \subseteq M $ such that $(M^-,\in^{M^-})$ is a model of $\sf T$?

Where: $\in ^ {M^-}$ is the restriction of $\in^M$ to $M^-$

Also, is the opposite true? That is if we swap $\sf ZF+\neg C$ and $\sf ZFC$ in the above statement, would the result be true?

Comment: Do you require that $M^-$ be an element, not just subset, of $M$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, No $M^-$ is just a subset of $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any countable model of $\sf ZF$ has a top extension satisfying $V=L$, although it may or may not be well-founded. That is known as the Barwise extension theorem.

So if you at least allow us to focus on countable models, the answer is positive.

---

In the other direction, well, forcing and symmetric extensions provide you an easy solution.